# No Empathy Autostart in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, empathy, autostart

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 from scratch and configured two accounts in the account manager and gave permission to Empathy to access them.

After a reboot, Empathy won't autostart so I have to start it manually from Unity chat applet, Empathy option.

After starting EMpathy, everything works as expected, and I can chat with my friends.

I need Empathy to autostart at logon

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Unity, just search 'Startup Applications' in the Dash
and add Empathy to the list

(this command is empathy)

Comment: Ooohh, man, the old school tools! will try.

Comment: in the command field I simply put empathy and I'm happy again!. It would be great that Ubuntu have an option in system configuration window to manage this!

Comment: you can create a custom .desktop file in /usr/share/applications that adds a link to the control panel. Did that once with the cinnamon Control Panel